# Is double shot and triple shot additive?

Tags: maplestory

I'm playing Jett, and I just reached level 30 and got a class upgrade. I now have the Triple Shot skill that improves the damage of the Double Shot. My question is, does it overwrite the damage of Double Shot, or add to it? For example, the minimum level required for Double Shot to get Triple Shot is 10, so would having a level 5 Triple Shot skill level with a level 20 Double Shot skill level, put out more damage than having a level 5 Triple Shot with a level 10 Double Shot skill level?

Answer (score 1):

Triple Shot gives like 3% per skill level so 124 + 15 is 139% x 3 shots, which is higher than 165 x 2 shots (max level 20).

To be honest, I HIGHLY suggest that you try to put the rest of your skill points into Double Shot after you max everything else in 1st job.

Triple Shot is basically an upgrade of Double Shot, in which case, you won't be using Double Shot anymore on 2nd job or higher.

Addictive? Yes it's additive. So this means that if my damage range is 1000, it will be 1000 damage of 3 lines. Well, damage is random but you have a range anyway so it should pick a value within that range.